# Is it possible to retrieve duration of less than 1 second from the Google Maps Distance Matrix API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to reduce uncertainty when using the Google Maps Distance Matrix API to extract journey time and distance data between a start and end node on the road network to calculate average speeds over fairly short distances (30m to 500m).

I am using the Python Googlemaps library

The standard journey time provided by the API is at 1 second i.e. integer resolution. Does anyone know if there is a command to extract the journey time at a finer temporal resolution of e.g 0.1 seconds when calling journey distance and duration data from the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the ["unit systems" section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#unit_systems) in the API documentation,

> **`duration`**: The length of time it takes to travel this route, expressed in **seconds** (the value field) and as text. The textual representation is localized according to the query's language parameter.

There are no [Required](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#required-parameters) or [Optional](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#optional-parameters) parameters that can change this setting to return values expressed as fractions of a second.